# Piecewise in 2D with quadrants as conditions

Tags: function-construction, vector, piecewise

I am trying to define a piecewise vector field. Can the condition be of the form I am using (i.e. a quadrant)? I can't also make `Piecewise` work with more than two pieces, why?

`nx[x_, y_] :=  Piecewise[{nx4[x, y], cond}, {-nx3[x, y], x y < -a/100 && x < -a/100}]`
`ny[x_, y_] :=  Piecewise[{(1 - nx4[x, y]^2)^(1/2), x y > a/100 && x > a/100}, {(1 - nx3[x, y]^2)^(1/2), x y < -a/100 && x < -a/100}]`

I get

`"The first argument {Sqrt[(y^2/(4 \
Plus[<<2>>]^2)+(1/2+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<4>>])^2+Sqrt[Power[<<2>>] \
Plus[<<2>>]])/(1/4\Power[<<2>>]\Power[<<2>>]+Plus[<<3>>]^2)]/Sqrt[2],\
x\ y>1/100&&x>1/100} of Piecewise is not a list of pairs."`

Comment: You did get the syntax wrong. Look at `Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x}, {1/2, -1 < x <= 0}}, 0]` to see how it is correctly done.